# how to auto create new app in Google Play by API

Tags: android, fastlane

**Hi**,

I have to build many app from one source frequently.

So i want to create new app auto in Google Play by API for convenient, and after that i will use Supply mobile in [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) to upload metadata.

Anyone can help me solve this case :)
Thanks for your investigating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Google there is no public API to create a new application on Google Play. They don't plan on adding one.

Source: I talked with them about this.